# GraphUser is null during Facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to integrate my android app with facebook SDK. When I try to login to facebook through my app, I am getting a null value for GraphUSer in the following function call:

> onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user)

Can anyone please help me to understand why this can happen?